# Excel 2010 VLOOKUP #N/A Result when numbers are in different number formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

Using a VLOOKUP function and the lookup value may be something like 100034 and when I click on the cell it tells me it is of the "General" format. Where the lookup value is located in my data range that I'm searching has it as a "Number" format. I've tried changing them to be the same (both general, both number, both accounting, etc.) and it doesn't work.

For some weird reason, two of the cells of the reference data were showing up at "Number" format and they work so that is why I am assuming this is the problem, however even after changing those to a different format it still works. Any other suggestions? Below is an example of my VLOOKUP syntax.

```
VLOOKUP(C19,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to replicate this behaviour was by forcing the lookup value to be treated as text (by prefixing it with a ' when typing it into the cell). That could happen fairly easy if the data's been pasted in from somewhere else or something like that.

**If** that's what's happened to your lookup values, the following formula should do the trick:

```
VLOOKUP(VALUE(C19),Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

That utilises the *VALUE* function, which instructs Excel to attempt to parse a number stored as a string into an actual number. The documentation for that function is available here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VALUE-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2

It will, however, error out if you feed it something that can't be parsed into a number. You could handle that using *IFERROR*:

```
VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VALUE(C19),C19),Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

That just tells Excel to pass the value through unchanged if it can't convert it to a number. That way if you have non-numeric values in your data, it'll still work. It might not be the most elegant solution, but it works.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. I opened the doc in Excel 2013 and was able to use the NUMBERVALUE function and it worked as well and didn't realize VALUE was a potential function.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: check your data **values** for consistency. **Format** does not matter.

Long answer:

The format of a cell is not important. It's the underlying value that counts.

A cell can contain text that looks like a number. You can format this cell as "Number", but the underlying value is still text.

Using a format can be a great way to find out if the cell contains text or not. If you can change the number format to another number format, for example use a format that has decimals and increase or decrease the number of decimals showing in the cell, then the cell value is a number. If it does not budge, it's not a number.

Once you have identified which cells contain text instead of a number, you can quickly coerce them to be numbers with this method:

- type a 0 into a cell and copy that cell
- select the cells that contain text
- use Paste Special and in the dialog tick "Add", then OK

This mathematical operation will turn numbers stored as text into real numbers.